# unable to return result in controller in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, model-view-controller, model

I am not getting result on controller but get result in model. I have also return result data from model. I did also use callback(), but did not get result.

## model code

```
//here is my code User.js(model)

var con = require('../config/connection');

module.exports = {
    validateUser: function (username = null, password = null) {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_id='" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            return result;
        });
    }
}

//contoller code

const UserModel = require('../model/User');

router.post('/validate', (req, res) => {
    var password = md5(req.body.password);
    var result = UserModel.validateUser(req.body.emailid, password);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Please let me know,where am i doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using callback to call the db query, but at the same time your validate function also should be asynchronous. Try changing your code like this:

**User.js(model)**

```
var con = require('../config/connection');

module.exports = {
    validateUser: function (username = null, password = null, cb = () => {}) {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_id='" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if(err) cb(err);
            else cb(null, result);
        });
    }
}
```

**contoller code:**

```
const UserModel = require('../model/User');

router.post('/validate', (req, res) => {
    var password = md5(req.body.password);
    UserModel.validateUser(req.body.emailid, password, (err, result) => {
        if(err) console.log("error => ", err);
        else console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callback or promise for this, please check this below solution,

```
 validateUser: function(username = null,password = null,callback){
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_id='"+username+"' AND password = '"+password+"'";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    callback(result)
});
}

# contoller code 
const UserModel = require('../model/User');
router.post('/validate',(req,res)=>{
  var password =  md5(req.body.password);
  UserModel.validateUser(req.body.emailid,password,function(result){
      console.log(result);
  });
})
```